# fancybox V2 - How to modify size of white border (skin?) on large image

Tags: jquery, fancybox, border, fancybox-2

Regarding Fancybox V2 - Is there way to modify the size of white border (skin?) on large image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the API option `padding` like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        padding: 50 // or whatever, 0 = nothing
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lso90kvy/)**

Comment: Thanks! But if this isn't part of the .js file, then can I just include it inside a current snippet on the html page:

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            css : {
                'background' : 'rgba(58, 42, 45, 0.95)'
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>

Thanks!